# persistent local tty session with java

Tags: java, shell, tty

I`m developing a web shell client, with tab functionality "code completion" and a have a question.
Anyone know a way to open a local tty persistent connection where I can to execute multiple commands with one session, i wont like to exec all time Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");
Any suggestion?
Regards

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");` do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh");` and hold on to the `Process` object. Then you can write commands to the OutputStream provided by its `getOutputStream()` method - I presume you're already getting the output by reading its InputStream.