# Getting error while executing the docker command from java program

Tags: java, docker

I tried to execute the following docker command from Java code:

```
command: ***docker exec -it reverent_hoover date***
```

(Here, `reverente_hoover` is the container name.)

When I executed the above command from Linux, it gave me the following output:

> Wed May  6 05:19:28 UTC 2015

But when I tried to execute it from Java code, it gave me this error:

> time="2015-05-05T19:31:19+05:30" level="fatal" msg="cannot enable tty
>   mode on non tty input"

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Issue 10734](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10734) mentions:

> The java process is not providing a TTY to the docker CLI but you've asked for a TTY by specifying `-t` in your command.
>   So, does the image actually need a TTY? If not, don't specifiy `-t`... if the image doesn't need stdin at all don't specify `-i` either.
>
> If it does need the TTY, then you'll need to setup the TTY for your command and it should work.

For example, see "[persistent local tty session with java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357989/6309)"

> Instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");` do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh");` and hold on to the `Process` object

"[Runtime.exec with Unix console programs](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/runtime-exec-with-unix-console-programs/)" illustrates that in the context of using `less`:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sh", "-c",
            "less >/dev/tty"});
    OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
    out.write("Lengthy message".getBytes());
    out.close();
    System.out.println("=> "+p.waitFor());
```

Comment: I need only the output like "Wed May  6 05:19:28 UTC 2015". So In which format I need to give the command.

Comment: @KaviChinna I only meant to explain the tty part.

Comment: Anyway, I got the output by removing -it flag from the command.